# Unable to move from one fragment to another

Tags: kotlin, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-navigation-bar

I am trying to set up an `activity` with a `fragment` with a `recyclerview` and a botom navigation menu. When I tap on the 'Dashboard', I can see the progress bar and it updates the data from `Firestore` but when I hit the Quizzes I cannot see the progress bar or new data. All I am seeing is the same data. I think it's not moving to other fragment.

As a beginner I do not know the actual working of `fragments` and `recyclerview` I am doing it with the help of people and resources available online.
I couldn't figure out where the problem is. I can provide more codes if needed.

NOTE: I am not getting any error.

`bottom_nav_menu.xml`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_dashboard"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_vector_dashboard"
        android:title="Dashboard" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_quizzes"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_vector_quizzes"
        android:title="Quizzes" />

</menu>
```

`mobile_navigation.xml`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/navigation_dashboard">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_dashboard"
        android:name="com.example.quiz.ui.fragments.DashboardFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_dashboard"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_dashboard" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_quiz"
        android:name="com.example.quiz.ui.fragments.QuizFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_products"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_quiz" />

</navigation>
```

`activity_dashboard.xml`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/app_gradient_color_background"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/colorWhite"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/colorWhite"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />


    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

`fragment_dashboard.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    tools:context=".ui.fragments.DashboardFragment">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_dashboard_items"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_list_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_no_dashboard_items_found"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="no_dashboard_item_found"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

`fragment_quiz.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    tools:context=".ui.fragments.QuizFragment">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvQuizzesFrag"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_list_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_no_products_found"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="NO QUIZZES TODAY"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

`DashboardActivity.kt`

```
package com.example.quiz.ui.activities

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupActionBarWithNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupWithNavController
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
import com.example.quiz.R

class DashboardActivity : BaseActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard)
     
        supportActionBar!!.setBackgroundDrawable(
            ContextCompat.getDrawable(
                this@DashboardActivity,
                R.drawable.app_gradient_color_background
            )
        )


        val navView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)

        val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
        val navController = navHostFragment.navController

        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(
                R.id.navigation_quiz,
                R.id.navigation_dashboard
            )
        )
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)

        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        doubleBackToExit()
    }
}
```

Can you tell me where these `R.id.navigation_quiz`, `R.id.navigation_dashboard` should be referring to? Whether to the `bottom_nav_menu.xml` or `mobile_navigation.xml`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think it's not moving to `Quiz Fragment` then it might be because your `BottomNavigation` is not working correctly....

For bottom navigation to work correct with Nav Controller the `id's` of items in `bottom_nav_menu.xml` and `moile_navigation.xml` must be same

In your case the `id` of dashboard is same in  `bottom_nav_menu.xml` and `moile_navigation.xml` but for quiz the id's are different in both of these files, it is `@+id/navigation_quizzes` in `bottom_nav_menu.xml`  and in `moile_navigation.xml` it is `@+id/navigation_quiz`

**Make the id's same in both files**

bottom_nav_menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_dashboard"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_vector_dashboard"
        android:title="Dashboard" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_quiz"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_vector_quiz"
        android:title="Quizzes" />
</menu>
```

moile_navigation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/navigation_dashboard">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_dashboard"
        android:name="com.example.quiz.ui.fragments.DashboardFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_dashboard"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_dashboard" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_quiz"
        android:name="com.example.quiz.ui.fragments.QuizFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_products"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_quiz" />

</navigation>
```